# Java Send mouse/key events to program wen its not in active

Tags: java, mouseevent, desktop-application

Is it possible to simulate **click/keyevent** only in a frame not throw whole pc. I saw a lot of tutorials talking about Java `Robot` class which does that , but I'm asking if it is posible to send for example arrow up **keyevent** when the frame is minimized.

Actually I have Java loader which loads flash object and I can do the clicks/keypress with the `Robot` class when the Windown is active (@**AdelBoutros**: I think he means visible), but how to simulate that when the Windown is not active. Is there any way to send keyevent? mouse click x,y?

Comment: I know i could bring window to front, but any other way?
Like send keyevent press with code directly only to frame.

Comment: Unless you have control over the frame, you need support for native OS libraries to do that. Java alone can not do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the AWT event queue and push events there:

`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().push(newEventQueue)`

To do this you need access to the "victim" application. If you do not want to modify its code you can create special generic starter type that runs `main()` method of other class, connects to event queue (as I shown) and exposes this queue for remote access (via TCP, JMX, web service etc).

You can also inject your code into application using agent (see java.lang.instrument package).